# I need help creating a warning command in Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I did this command to warn members and send a message in the DM, but I want the bot to tell the members in which server they were warned.

```js
if (command === "warn") {
    let dUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.reply("You can't use that command!")
    if (!dUser) return message.channel.send("Can't find user!")
    let dMessage = args.join(" ").slice(22);
    if (dMessage.length < 1) return message.reply('what is the reason???')

    dUser.send(`${dUser}, You have been warned for doing ${dMessage}`)

    message.channel.send(`${dUser} has been warned for doing ${dMessage} :thumbsdown:`)
```

Comment: i recommend use a database to store the data which user get warn how many time.
if the user has been warn let's say 3 times then perma ban the user

Answer (score 0):

`Message` has a property `Guild`, which is the guild in which the message was sent. You can just use `message.guild.name` to get the guild name.

---

```js
if (command === "warn") {
    let dUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.reply("You can't use that command!")
    if (!dUser) return message.channel.send("Can't find user!")
    let dMessage = args.join(" ").slice(22);
    if (dMessage.length < 1) return message.reply('what is the reason???')

    dUser.send(`${dUser}, You have been warned for doing ${dMessage} in the server ${message.guild.name}`)

    message.channel.send(`${dUser} has been warned for doing ${dMessage} :thumbsdown:`)
```